# i can't connect to my audio file using three.js method load with webpack2

Tags: javascript, three.js

i am using webpack2 and i have npm installed package that can run mp3 files , but three.js couldn't get the file

```
 module.exports.music = function(){
var listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add(listener);
var sound = new THREE.Audio(listener);
var audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
audioLoader.load('../audio/YouBitch.mp3', function(buffer){
    sound.setBuffer(buffer);
    sound.setLoop(true);
    sound.setVolume(0.5);
    sound.play();
})
  }
```

the console says http://localhost:8080/audio/YouBitch.mp3 404 not found
same problem accuars while i tried to load json file using threejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are serving the webpack bundle on your web server the path will be relative to the website url not the local file system. Therefore you will need to serve them through your web server.

Comment: i can not load it on my localhost with webpack?